# Way to dynamically set a React Navigation screen title using MobX store value?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, mobx

On my default React Navigation tab screen I'd like to set the screen's title to a value from a MobX store. It's my understanding that the only way to do this is to pass the value via a param--so I can't just put the MobX value in the 'title: ' field... but as this is the 'default' screen I'm not passing it anything.

Default screen:

```
export default class HomeScreen extends Component {
  static navigationOptions = ({ navigation, screenProps }) => ({
    title: `This is ${navigation.state.params.title}`,
```

I've attempted to make use of setParams during componentWillMount, but console.log shows me it must be happening too late, so I get an empty object in the title.

Any idea how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same problem today and figured it out.

Simply change your `navigationOptions` to a function instead of an object, that way it will re-evaluate on state changes. Here's the fix for you, as described by the manual at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/intro/headers#Header-interaction-with-screen-component:

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
  const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
  const title = `This is ${params.title}`;
  return { title };
};
```

Comment: How are you changing the value of title after the fact with mobx? It looks like you would need to use `navigation.setParams`.

Comment: @JoshuaPinter I actually use the screenProps with MobX to display the username on their profile page in the header. When I update my store everything works as it should, haven't tried it with setParams…

Comment: Interesting. That probably works better. `setParams` works but it's a little janky.

Comment: Would love to see the full solution on using screenProps